# Python Pandas - How to filter a dataframe that has a column containing a dictionary, using the existence of a key?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, filter, key

Having a dataframe that has a dictionary column

```py
d = {'p1':[{'Apple':10},{'Ball': 20, 'Cat': 30}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

```
    p1
0   {'Apple': 10}
1   {'Ball': 20, 'Cat': 30}
```

I would like to filter rows where the key 'Ball' exists.

```
    p1
1   {'Ball': 20, 'Cat': 30}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `in` statement:

```
df = df[df['p1'].map(lambda x: 'Ball' in x)]

print (df)

                        p1
1  {'Ball': 20, 'Cat': 30}
```

Answer (score 4):

The following line will do

```
df[['Ball' in x.keys() for x in df.p1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read it as a dataframe with string values and use df.loc and df.column.str.contains() then:

```
d = {'p1':[{'Apple':10},{'Ball': 20, 'Cat': 30}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d,dtype='str')
df2 = df.loc[df.p1.str.contains('Ball')]
df2
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful for your understanding as well

```
d = {'p1':[{'Apple':10},{'Ball': 20, 'Cat': 30}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


df2 = df['p1'].apply(pd.Series) # would break the dictionary into different columns 

df2

   Apple  Ball   Cat
0   10.0   NaN   NaN
1    NaN  20.0  30.0
```

from here, you can pick the columns having Ball directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [`str.get`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html#pandas.Series.str.get):

```
df[df['p1'].str.get('Ball').notna()]
```